# ROracle bind range of dates

Tags: r, bind, roracle

I want to send to oracle via ROracle query with bind parameters which inculde range of dates for a date column.

I try to run :

```
idsample <- 123
strdate <- "TO_DATE('01/02/2017','DD/MM/YYYY')"
enddate <- "TO_DATE('01/05/2017','DD/MM/YYYY')"

res <- dbGetQuery(myconn,"SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE MYID = :1 AND MYDATE BETWEEN :2 AND :3", data=data.frame(MYID =idsample , MYDATE=c(strdate,enddate )))
```

but I get error :

"bind data does not match bind specification"

Comment: no need to shout

Comment: SQL is a loud language :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could find no documentation which covers using more than one positional parameter, but if one parameter corresponds to a single column of a data frame, then by this logic three parameters should correspond to three columns:

```
idsample <- 123
strdate <- "TO_DATE('01/02/2017', 'DD/MM/YYYY')"
enddate <- "TO_DATE('01/05/2017', 'DD/MM/YYYY')"
res <- dbGetQuery(myconn,
                  paste0("SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE MYID = :1 AND ",
                         "MYDATE BETWEEN TO_DATE(:2, 'DD/MM/YYYY') AND TO_DATE(:3, 'DD/MM/YYYY')"),
                   data=data.frame(idsample, strdate, enddate))
```

Note that there is nothing special about `strdate` and `enddate` from the point of view of the API, such that they should be passed as vector.

**Edit:**

The problem with making `TO_DATE` a parameter is that it will probably end up being escaped as a string.  In other words, with my first approach you would end up with the following in your `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE MYDATE BETWEEN
    'TO_DATE('01/02/2017','DD/MM/YYYY')' AND 'TO_DATE('01/05/2017','DD/MM/YYYY')'
```

In other words, the `TO_DATE` function calls ends up being a string.  Instead, bind the date strings only.

Comment: I tried your suggestion. now I get :   
"a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected"

Comment: @oomm Put single quotes around everything in your call to `TO_DATE`.  Let me know if this fixes all the problems.

Comment: No. sorry.. I had it before in my code. just in this sample it was ommitted . I will fix it in the question. the query works fine without bind parameters

Comment: Is the `MYDATE` column a date type in your Oracle table?

Comment: I don't have an Oracle database here to use for testing.  May I request that you try the following query: `dbGetQuery(myconn, "SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE MYDATE = :1", data=data.frame(strdate))`

Comment: Just one positional parameter, a bona fide date, compared directly against a date column.  If you still get the same numeric error, then we're missing something obvious here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157800/discussion-between-oo-mm-and-tim-biegeleisen).

Comment: I still get the numeric error  when only comparing one value to the date. but binding only the id is working fine...

Comment: Try binding the date itself _inside_ the call to `TO_DATE`.